# creating local branch from remote develop branch

Tags: git

I want to create a local and a remote branch named test from the develop branch on origin. However, even though my current local branch is tracking origin/develop when I checkout the new branch it takes origin/master.
Therefore, I have to follow the steps below to get a test branch on both remote and local.

```
git checkout -b test ( By default it picks origin/master though my current branch tracks origin/develop)
git fetch origin
git reset --hard origin/develop 
git push -u origin test
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-checkout.html)

```
git checkout -b test --track origin/develop
```

should do the trick.

---

As extra goodies, if you want to create a local branch to track a remote branch with the same name, you can be lazy an omit the `-b` option

```
git checkout --track origin/develop
```

will create and checkout a local branch named `develop`, thus being equivalent to

```
git checkout -b develop --track origin/develop
```

From the doc

> As a convenience, --track without -b implies branch creation.
>
> [...]
>
> If no -b option is given, the name of the new branch will be derived from the remote-tracking branch.

Comment: Thanks, but can I actually track origin/develop and create a new branch 'test' on both remote and local repository in one step? Maybe asking for too much.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of and I'm pretty sure you can't. You will have to push the local branch in order to achieve what you want. So in the end the whole procedure boils down to 2 commands: create the local branch and push it.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with [Git 2.23](https://github.blog/2019-08-16-highlights-from-git-2-23/), you can also use:

```sh
git switch -t origin/<branch>
```

It creates and checkouts to a new local branch named `<branch>` tracking the remote `origin/<branch>`.

More details on [the documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch#Documentation/git-switch.txt--t).